# verseで連射速度向上は実現可能かどうか

Tags: プログラミング言語

Unreal Engine for Fortnite（UEFN）で使用するVreseについて

LegoFortnite上で武器の連射速度を制御することは可能でしょうか。

Vreseを勉強し始めたところで、なにが・どこまで実現可能か不明なためお伺いしたいです。